# Concurrent access to a @Lock(LockType.WRITE) method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, ejb, jms

What am i trying to accomplish:

I have a JMS queue and I want to asynchronously get elements from that queue and send to a Printer. This printer is very specific and dumb so it can't queue on it's on or buffer anything at all. I must perform 5 steps in sequence on this printer and the steps of a queued elemet must not overlap the steps of another element. For each step the printer will return 1 on success and another number on failure.

The current implementation is an MDB with an **onMessage** method call to a @Lock(LockType.WRITE) method from a Singleton ejb.

The MDB:

```
    @MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup",
        propertyValue = "jms/MyQueue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
        propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")})

public class SimpleMessageBean implements MessageListener {

@Resource
private MessageDrivenContext mdc;
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SimpleMessageBean");

@EJB
private Print print;

public SimpleMessageBean() {
}

@Override
public void  onMessage(Message inMessage) {
    try {
        if (inMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "MESSAGE BEAN: Message received: {0}", inMessage.getBody(String.class));

            String params[] = ((TextMessage) inMessage).getText().split("\\s+");
            print.doStuff(params[0], params[1]);
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Error")
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Rollback Happening: {0}", e.toString());
        mdc.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

The Singleton:

```
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Startup
@Singleton
@AccessTimeout(value = 120000)
public class Print {

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SimpleMessageBean");

public Print() {
}

@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public void doStuff(String cpf, String value) throws Exception{
        try{
            int return;
            return = Bematech.AbreCupom(cpf);
            System.out.println("Stage0 = " + return);

            return = Bematech.VendeItem("111112", "Parking", "FF", "hours", "1", 2, value, "%", "00,00");
            System.out.println("Stage1 = " + return);

            return = Bematech.IniciaFechamentoCupom("D", "%", "00,00");
            System.out.println("Stage2 = " + return);

            return = Bematech.EfetuaFormaPagamento("Dinheiro", value);
            System.out.println("Stage3 = " + return);

            return = Bematech.TerminaFechamentoCupom("Thankyou ofr your support");
            System.out.println("Stage4 = " + return);


        }catch ( Exception MensagemErro ){
            throw MensagemErro;
        }
}
```

I expected this implementation to receive the data from the queue and print it one element at a time as the doStuff() method is locked, AKA:

```
Stage0=1
Stage1=1
Stage2=1
Stage3=1
Stage4=1
Stage0=1
Stage1=1
Stage2=1
Stage3=1
Stage4=1
Stage0=1
...
```

But sometimes (seems to be random but it happens more often when several messages are queued at once) i get two concurrent access to the print method:

```
Stage0=1
Stage1=1
Stage0=1
Stage2=1
Stage1=1
Stage3=1
Stage2=1
...
```

From what is being print I can see that 2 elements are overlapping in the printer access.

Usefull info:

Java EE 7.
Glassfish 4-0.
Not Using JBOSS.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What you see printed shows overlapping but is the printer getting the commands in correct sequence and everything fine? Looks like printer is returning 1 for all commands. If printer commands are not fine, then the first thing I would check is whether you are really dealing with only 1 instance of Print object. If it is, then the next thing is to check why LockType.WRITE isn't working as you intended. Maybe use synchronized keyword on the doStuff() method.

Comment: The printer returns 1 when the command works fine. But as the commands are overllaping so does the print result, i get the print results all mixed with stuff from both queue elements.
As for the synchronized keyword it changed nothing at all....
As for the instance of the print object, I am using the manufacturer JAR, how can I check how many instances of the object i am deling with?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  The code above is not syntactically correct.  'return' is a java reserved keyword, so you can not use it as a variable name ( int return; ).  If it's not the same as your actual code it would be very difficult to figure out the problem.  When you import @Singleton, are you sure you're importing javax.ejb.Singleton rather than javax.inject.Singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronized keyword solved my problem. Did not find out what was wrong with original code.