# JPA query not finding entity after persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I have an AngularJS front-end which makes multiple requests to different resources on a Java back-end running Wildfly 10.

Every resource endpoint queries the database (MySQL 5.6) to find the user using a unique user ID from the access token (It's not a Primary key it has an unique index).

In case the user is not found on the database, I create it from the access token information, see bellow:

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    ...

}

public abstract class AbstractResource extends AbstractService {

    @EJB
    UserService userService;

    @EJB
    UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

    public User getUser(AccessToken token) {

        User user = userService.findByKcId(token.getUserId());
        if (user == null) {
            user = userRegistrationService.findOrCreateUser(token);
        }

        return user;
    }

    ...
}
```

I created a singleton to make sure the user is only created if it really doesn't exists already.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class UserRegistrationService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    UserService userService;

    public User findOrCreateUser(AccessToken token) {
        String kcId = token.getUserId();

        User user = this.findByKcId(kcId);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
            user.setKcId(kcId);   

            ...

            em.persist(user);
            em.flush();
            em.refresh(user);
        }

        return user;
    }

    private User findByKcId(String kcId) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
        criteria.select(user).where(cb.equal(user.get(User_.kcId), kcId));

        List<User> users = em.createQuery(criteria)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getResultList();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return users.get(0);
    }

    ...
}
```

But for some reason the first time the user signs-in, all requests (our home page makes 3 async requests) triggers a INSERT on the database which results in:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry ...
```

Even though the first request already created the new user on the database. After the first sign-in everything works fine.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I created a method inside UserRegistrationService to search for the user and share the same EM with the findOrCreateUser method.

Also here it is the EntityManager hashCode() output:

```
11:53:32,344 INFO  [stdout] (default task-21) UserService.findKcById: 11694883
11:53:32,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-21) UserRegistrationService.findOrCreateUser: 212546987
11:53:32,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-21) UserRegistrationService.findKcById: 212546987
11:53:32,423 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) UserService.findKcById: 11694883
11:53:32,495 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) UserRegistrationService.findOrCreateUser: 212546987
11:53:32,495 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) UserRegistrationService.findKcById: 212546987
11:53:32,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-26) UserService.findKcById: 11694883
```

**UPDATE 2: LOG**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '8f262ed0-3868-449e-aea8-b2af55209479' for key 'kc_id2_UNIQUE'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the EntityManager references?  My guess is you have 2 different EMs (and therefore 2 different transactions).

Comment: @SteveEbersole just edited my code. I injected the EntityManager on an abstract class. Also they are 3 different requests, aren't they already 3 different transactions one for each requests?

Comment: I dont actually understand why would `AbstractService` have its extending classes as members. It i as design (or rather lack of it) flaw to me.

Comment: @Antoniossss you are right, just edited to reflect the real design. I had abbreviated for simplicity and didn't notice the error.

Comment: I already mentioned what I think the error is: I would guess you are actually using 2 different EMs.  That's easy to verify.  Print the System hashCodes of the various EM reference in play here.  As i mentioned below I am fairly certain this is a problem in how you design these services.

Comment: @SteveEbersole I moved EM from the abstract class and injected at each service. When I print their hashCodes I get 3 different values. Maybe its relevant to mention that my deployment it's an EAR with services deployed as EJB JAR and resources deployed inside a WAR.

Comment: So that right there is your problem.  You have 3 EMs, ergo 3 JDBC Connections and therefore (most likely) 3 different transactions.

Comment: @SteveEbersole So I can't simply inject EM in each @ Stateless service? Do I have to share a single EM across all application? See: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_in_an_ejb_injected

Comment: You should use a single Session/EntityManager for a given use-case.  For performance as well as sanity :)

Comment: @SteveEbersole is is possible to have single transaction and multiple connections sharing it? (naaaah) You were right about different EMs but this does not explain why it fails if db access is synchronized;/ Do you have any ideas in this direction?

Comment: "is it possible..." Sure, its called XA :)

I'm not understanding the term "asynch" as used here.  Do you mean something like multiple asynch calls from the webpage via REST or somesuch?  If so that is never going to work unless you use a different approach.  The asynch nature (with no other controls) effectively means this would never work

Comment: @SteveEbersole Yes, multiple async calls from different controllers using javascript on the webpage via REST. Meaning they are fired at the same time for 3 different REST resources. Why would not work? I`m serializing the requests and INSERT and after that querying the DB before a new INSERT...

Answer (score 0):

> (our home page makes 3 async requests)

I assume these request are invoked not 1 by one byt all at once right (async after all)

So simply speaking you got racing conditions. 
To prove if i am right or wrong, for tests, make `findOrCreate` method `synchronized`
so delcare it as follows:

```
public synchronized User findOrCreateUser(AccessToken token)
```

it should fix the problem (ad nas a side effect it will serialize requests but this is a different problem)

Comment: I agree it should be a racing condition. I tried, but didn't work. Shouldn't the singleton address this  issue since it's default to @Lock(LockType.WRITE)?

Comment: Looks like not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493213/concurrent-access-to-a-locklocktype-write-method

Comment: I checked the question but 'synchronized' didn't work for me. I`m guessing is something related to hibernate cache. Maybe the first query after the insert is getting its results from the cache?

Comment: Well it would seem you have a singleton on one of the things extending from the base class where you inject the EM.  Obviously not all concrete instances of that bass class are going to be the same singleton.  Ergo, you still potentially have multiple EMs at play.

Look, its infinitely simpler to test this using a simplified driver that just makes the Hibernate/JPA calls to convince yourself that this works (I know it does).  Then you are left with the design of your services as the only possible culprit and can focus on fixing that.

Comment: @SteveEbersole by a simplified driver um mean a single EM?

Comment: @Bruno Are you sure that user persistance is done only in code snippet you have provided? Maybe wrong mapping and relation handling that we dont see causes cascade insert of user? To be honest it must be it as `synchronization` had to work.

Comment: @Bruno assuming that Steve may be right about singleton not beeing singleton at all, if you use `synchronized(UserRegistrationService.class){//your db code}` you are **guaranteed** to have synchronization between multiple instances (just in case). If the code still fails, then it is either different place you are persisting user as well, or cascade insert due to persisting of some dependencies and not setting actual created user as its parent.

Comment: @Bruno And as you have 3 requests, then it would be logical to have 2 exact constrain violations. Is it true? Do you have 2 exceptions and they have the same stacktrace pointing to the code you have provided?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes I have 2 exceptions.

Comment: @Bruno with the exact same stacktrace right? If so - apply `synchronized(UserRegistrationService.class){//your db code}` if still fails - Steve is right you have multiple different EntityManagers - but even so - it  still fails due racing conditions.

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried the synchronization block and didn't work. Why Would it be a wrong mapping or relation mapping issue since it get inserted the first time? After all I get the error: EJB Invocation failed on component UserRegistrationService for method public User UserRegistrationService.findOrCreateUser with duplicate index exception

Comment: @Bruno it is just an assumption that some cascading inserts may be trying to insert user.

anyway this does not make any sense as due to synchronization there is **no racing condition anymore** and you cant have as many entity managers as you want and still it should work. The only possible fact taht sync may would not work is due custom or multiple class loaders but i doubt this is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have logic error here

```
    User user = userService.findByKcId(token.getUserId());
    if (user == null) {
        user = new User();
        ...

        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(user);
    }
```

Maybe 
`userService.findByKcId(token.getUserId());`
is not returning user while it should due to eg. error in `SELECT` query.

Form future investigation:

- Show us the rest of user creation code
- Show us the exact `ConstrainViolation`
- Show us code for `userService.findByKcId`

But anyway IMHO it is find-or-create logic in concurrenc env (multiple async calls) will most likely have to be synchronized.

Comment: @Bruno I admin it looks legit. So if it is not racing conditions I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: @Bruno just remember to post the solution if you find one, as I am very curious what is going on overhere :)